# Removing an `int` from a fixed-sized array

Tags: java

I've written a code for removing the `number` from an array. When I run my code, it happens not to remove the `number` but instead gives me another `number`. For example, when I pass number `44` in order to remove it, the ouput happens to be `3` instead of removing it. What could be the problem?

Given input:

```
2 5 33 44 3 8 6 7 4
```

Sample output:

```
2 5 33 3 3 8 6 7 4
```

Code:

```
public class RemoveAtIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = {2, 5, 33, 44, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4};
        int[] output = removeFromIndex(myArray, 44);
        for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(output[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] removeFromIndex(int[] myArray, int num)
    {
        int[] resultArray = new int[myArray.length - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i] != num){
                resultArray[i] = myArray[i]; 
            }
            else
                resultArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see how your program behaves?

Comment: You just duplicated one number instead of shifting all indices by one. Furthermore, I doubt that your `sample input` and `sample output` are generated by the program. Both have a length of `9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`as the length of two arrays are different and you are using the same variable `i` to iterate when assigning in the `for-loop`

So I've modified the code as `i` for one array and `j` for other array as

```
public static int[] removeFromIndex(int[] myArray, int num) {
        int[] resultArray = new int[myArray.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] != num) {
                resultArray[j++] = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
```

Comment: I was about to post this same hing

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of this line: `resultArray[j++] = myArray[i];`? What does it do when the matching number is found? Thanks in advance! @Madhan

Comment: add values to `resultArray` and iterate to next index. As you see the `i` `myArray` index will be incremented for each iteration. we need to increment the `j` `resultArray` only if it matches the condition

Comment: @Madhan, but does it mean if `myArray[i] == num` then it skips the number?

Comment: NEVERMIND! Figured out everything! Thank you!

Comment: yes here in your case if the value is 44 it will skip and store the rest to the array

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 public static int[] removeFromIndex(int[] myArray, int num)
 {
    int[] resultArray = new int[myArray.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
       if(myArray[i] != num){
          resultArray.push(myArray[i]); 
       }
       else{
          return myArray;
       }

       return resultArray;
    }
}
```

You might have to include stack.push class

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with arrays of different size so you'll need two separate indexes when you're assigning the contents from the old array to the new array with the number of interest removed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] myArray = {2, 5, 33, 44, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4};
        int[] output = removeFromIndex(myArray, 44);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}

public static int[] removeFromIndex(int[] myArray, int num) {
    // Index counter for the new array
    int index = 0;
    int[] resultArray = new int[myArray.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        // Skip the element that matches the number wanting to be removed
        if (myArray[i] == num) {
            continue;
        }

        resultArray[index] = myArray[i];
        index++;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Results:

```
[2, 5, 33, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4]
```

Are you allowed to use Java 8? If so you can just do the removal process with one line and get the same results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] myArray = {2, 5, 33, 44, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4};
        int[] output = removeFromIndex(myArray, 44);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}

public static int[] removeFromIndex(int[] myArray, int num) {
    return Arrays.stream(myArray).filter(n -> n != num).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of these lines:`resultArray[index] = myArray[i];
        index++;` If the matching number is found, does it simply skip it and overwrites it? @Shar1er80

Comment: @John You're original array has elements from indexes 0 - 8, the new array will have elements from 0 - 7.  If you try to just do a straight copy over from the old array to the new array, you'll result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  That's why you need two separate index counters.  1 index counter that will go through the old array (This is the variable i in the for loop) and 1 index counter that will go through the  new array (This is the variable index).

Comment: @John If you're allowed to use Java 8, you can avoid separate counters using streams if try using the additional answer I provided.